# Create grouped/stacked bar plots from multiple categories containing several labels inside a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have the following `pandas` dataframe (`df`) [*only an excerpt of the full dataframe*]:

```
   Name    Cat_1    Cat_2
0   foo        P    Apples, Pears, Cats
1   bar     R, M    Apples
2   bla        E    Pears
3   blu        F    Cats, Pears
4   boo        G    Apples, Pears
5   faa     P, E    Apples, Cats
```

I would like to create bar plots that are build from `Cat_1` and `Cat_2`. 
These columns contain multiple tags, which have to be use for plotting.

Currently, I am running this simple code to plot `Cat_1`:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (4,4))
s = df["Cat_1"].str.split(", ", expand = True).stack()
s.value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar', ax = ax)
```

This returns a nice bar plot for each of the different labels in `Cat_1` allowing multiple assignments (as intended).

One could apply the same to `Cat_2` and obtain a separate plot with the respective labels.

However, I want to have a single plot that is first "stacked" by `Cat_1` and subsequently the values are counted for `Cat_2`.

I guess a way to think of this is to build a nested dictionary that would look like the following:

```
{"P": {"Apples": 2, "Pears": 1, "Cats": 2}, "R": {"Apples": 1}, ....}
```

but at the same time keep track of the total count of `Cat_1`.

It does not matter whether its a grouped or stacked bar chart in the end.

Please take a look a the enclosed figure for a more visual idea:

[image]

Comment: Your title asks for a "grouped bar plot". After reading through it looks like you want either a grouped bar plot where each bar is roughly proportional to the length of characters in the string and then annotated on top of it. Is this correct? And are you set on using the pandas plot convenience function? I think it would be simpler to use mpl directly since you have a pretty specific plot.

Comment: @ak_slick I edited the title so it adapts to an `mpl` method as well. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for that. Next clarification. It looks like you are wanting one type of stacked bar chart with two applications. 1) that places Cat_1 on the X-axis with the height being the total count of strings contained within each corresponding Cat_2. And then your second use case is just using it the opposite way: with  sums of "P", "E" and "R" chunked for each "Apples", "Pears" and Cats" on the x-axis. I am reading this correctly?

Comment: 2) is the preferred way. Basically for each of the `Cat_1` total counts I want to create a cluster that contains `Cat_2` information (if available). So chunking one category with the other to indicate the contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty close if I understand correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Cat_1', 'Cat_2'])

df['Name'] = ['foo', 'bar', 'bla', 'blu', 'boo', 'faa']
df['Cat_1'] = ['P', 'R, M', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'P, E']
df['Cat_2'] = ['Apples, Pears, Cats', 'Apples', 'Pears', 'Cats, Pears', 'Apples, Pears', 'Apples, Cats']

# arrange data simply prepopulate with zero
df_pl = pd.DataFrame(columns=df["Cat_1"].str.split(", ", expand=True).stack().unique().tolist(),
                     index=df["Cat_2"].str.split(", ", expand=True).stack().unique().tolist(),
                     data=0)

# get chunk size for each combination
for x in df_pl.columns:
    ind = df.Cat_1.str.contains(x)
    for name in df_pl.index:
        df_pl.set_value(name, x, df.loc[ind, 'Cat_2'].str.contains(name).sum())

N = len(df_pl.columns)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

plotted = []
p = {}
for name in df_pl.index:
    bottoms = df_pl.index.isin(plotted).sum()
    p[name] = plt.bar(ind, df_pl.loc[name].values.tolist(), bottom=bottoms)
    plotted.append(name)

plt.ylabel('y_label')
plt.title('some plot')
plt.xticks(ind, df_pl.columns.tolist())
plt.legend(p.values(), p.keys())

plt.show()
```

[image: Example Output]

Comment: @Fourier is this what you are looking for?